# What is the equivalent of heroku logs in app engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

Im using app engine to deploy my node.js application, Im wondering what is the equivalent of `heroku logs` in app engine so that I could check whether my server is crashing or to see the requests made by users

I typed `gcloud --log-http`, but no luck it says to many argument

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this, technically if you want to have the equivalent of `heroku logs` on App engine simply type

```
gcloud app logs tail -s default
```

Hope that helps